# How to constrain right hand table in LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: posts and comment.  One post has many comments.

Often I want to retrieve all posts along with any comment they may have.  I do this with a left join as shown:

```
select p.post_id, p.content_status, p.post_title, c.comment_id, 
       c.content_status as comment_status 
from post p 
left join comment c on p.post_id = c.post
```

Now I want to exclude any posts or comments where the status is not 'Approved'.  I can constrain the post table no problems, and still return posts that have no comments.  As soon as I constrain the comments table though, I no longer retrieve posts that have no comments.

Here's the offending query:

```
select p.post_id, p.content_status, p.post_title, c.comment_id, 
       c.content_status as comment_status 
from post p  
left join comment c on p.post_id = c.post 
where p.content_status = 'Approved' and c.content_status = 'Approved'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the condition on the right-hand table into the `ON` clause.

Any condition in the `WHERE` clause will remove rows entirely, while conditions in the `ON` clause will - as you want - not remove the row but just prevent a match.

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.content_status, p.post_title, c.comment_id, 
       c.content_status AS comment_status 
FROM post p  
LEFT JOIN comment c 
  ON p.post_id = c.post AND c.content_status = 'Approved'
WHERE p.content_status = 'Approved'
```

[An SQLfiddle, courtesy of @hims056](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/590ac/3).

Comment: @hims056 Thanks, added it to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the condition on the left-joined table into the join condition:

```
select p.post_id, p.content_status, p.post_title, c.comment_id, c.content_status as comment_status
from post p
left join comment c
  on p.post_id = c.post
  and c.content_status = 'Approved'
where p.content_status = 'Approved'
```

It seems to be a little known fact that the ON clause of a JOIN may contain non-key related conditions.